# C++ Convert SQLVARCHAR to string

Tags: c++, string, varchar

I need to convert from a SQLVARCHAR to a string data type

Variable definitions as follows:

```
string strFirstName;

SQLVARCHAR rtnFirstName[50];
```

Want to be able to accomplish the following:

```
if (strFirstName.empty()) strFirstName = rtnFirstName;
```

Gives an error that the `binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'SQLVARCHAR[50]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What database API are you using? All the Google hits I can find for `SQLVARCHAR` say it's an unsigned char, so you can do something like this:

```
strFirstName = reinterpret_cast<char*>(rtnFirstName);
```